# Error in python Crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, baidu-map

I am trying to use a python scawler script to get the address information from baidu map. The following is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import re
import csv
import time
def BusinessFromBaiduDitu(citycode = '287',key_word='筛网',pageno=0):
    parameter = {
    "newmap": "1",
    "reqflag": "pcmap",
    "biz": "1",
    "from": "webmap",
    "da_par": "direct",
    "pcevaname": "pc4.1",
    "qt": "con",
    "c": citycode,        # 城市代码
    "wd": key_word,       # 搜索关键词
    "wd2": "",
    "pn": pageno,         # 页数
    "nn": pageno * 10,
    "db": "0",
    "sug": "0",
    "addr": "0",
    "da_src": "pcmappg.poi.page",
    "on_gel": "1",
    "src": "7",
    "gr": "3",
    "l": "12",
    "tn": "B_NORMAL_MAP",
        # "u_loc": "12621219.536556,2630747.285024",
    "ie": "utf-8",
    # "b": "(11845157.18,3047692.2;11922085.18,3073932.2)",  #这个应该是地理位置坐标，可以忽略
    "t": "1468896652886"}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://map.baidu.com/'
htm = requests.get(url, params=parameter, headers=headers)
htm = htm.text.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape')  # 转码
pattern = r'(?<=\baddress_norm":"\[).+?(?="ty":)'
htm = re.findall(pattern, htm)  # 按段落匹配

for r in htm:
    pattern = r'(?<=\b"\},"name":").+?(?=")'
    name = re.findall(pattern, r)
    #if not name:
    pattern = r'(?<=\b,"name":").+?(?=")'
    name = re.findall(pattern, r)
    print(name[0])  # 名称

    pattern = r'.+?(?=")'
    adr = re.findall(pattern, r)
    pattern = r'\(.+?\['
    address = re.sub(pattern, ' ', adr[0])
    pattern = r'\(.+?\]'
    address = re.sub(pattern, ' ', address)
    print(address)  # 地址

    pattern = r'(?<="phone":").+?(?=")'
    phone = re.findall(pattern, r)
    try:
        if phone[0] and '",' != phone[0]:
            phone_list = phone[0].split(sep=',')
        for number in phone_list:
            if re.match('1', number):
                print(citycode+name[0]+','+address+','+number)              
                writer.writerow((name[0], address, number))
except:
    continue
print(citycode + '  ' + key_word + '  ' + str(pageno))
```

when running this script, I receives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\map.py", line 41, in <module> htm = requests.get(url, params=parameter, headers=headers) NameError: name 'parameter' is not defined
```

As I see it the 'parameter' is define in the def module. why does this error occur? 
I am new to python and I'll appreciate any help.

Best regards.

Yeping Sun

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: The error I'm receiving is:                                                                                                                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\map.py", line 41, in <module>
    htm = requests.get(url, params=parameter, headers=headers)
NameError: name 'parameter' is not defined

Comment: Is there a reason why you're defining parameters inside Baidu() function? It appears like you error would be resolved if you defined parameters outside that function.

Comment: Your other option is to return parameter inside the function, then call parameter = function()

Comment: This is a script I find in the Internet. I also don't understand why the variable ‘parameter’ is defined inside Baidu(). I have tried defining the parameters outside it, but running the script gets nothing (there is nothing output). I guess there must be other problems in the script.

Comment: I posted an example on how data is returned from a function, I hope that helps clear things up. If there's no output from the script I imagine it's a far deeper problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter is undefined because of a couple reasons. You are defining the function BusinessFromBaiduDitu, but you are not calling it or return data from the function.

Here's an example to return data from a function:

```
def test():
     a = {"Test1":"1"}
     return a

outside_a = test()
print(outside_a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!                                                                           After adding the "return" and outside call, running the script now gives some address output. However now I get another error:                                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\map.py", line 75, in <module>
    print(citycode + '  ' + key_word + '  ' + str(pageno))
NameError: name 'citycode' is not defined

Comment: Not sure if you fixed this, but you probably want to call "c" instead of "citycode" or perhaps even "parameter['c']"